# Problem after Ubuntu 16.04 updated to nvidia driver 375.66

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

My Ubuntu 16.04 PC has updated today (against my will :-/) the nvidia driver to 375.66. Before, I had 375.38 installed (not sure of the 38 but something like that). Why did I update ? Well, Ubuntu did not give me the choice.  My PC has a Nvidia 1050 4Go graphic card. Everything worked fine before the update. Now I cannot make the new nvidia driver work. And moreover I am stuck on the screen resolution 1024x768 ! Of course I used the command

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

to remove everything and re-install the nvidia driver and that still does not work. **I do not use any external PPA**, only the supported fully-tested drivers. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. Instead of deleting my question, I post the solution because it could be helpful for other people. The cause of the problem is that I have to use several versions of gcc. I came back to version 5 using the command

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 100
--slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5 --slave /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-5
```

and the new driver installs smoothly.

Comment: How have you done to revert your drivers to the las version? I've a GTX970 an almos the same problem (I see some ramdon horizontal lines in the left side of the screen)

Comment: @eddieferetro I don't know how to do that; I had just completely removed the nvidia driver using sudo apt-get purge nvidia* and then re-installed it from scratch after changing the version of gcc to use.

Answer (score 0):

The NVIDIA driver package rebuilds its kernel module when the driver is updated and when the kernel is updated. If you use a newer version of GCC by putting one in the path, the kernel module cannot be built.

update-alternatives is a solution for switching between versions of GCC. However, it would be tedious to have to remember to switch back to the old version before any kernel or graphics driver update.

Instead, you can just put symlinks to the newer version of gcc, g++, gcc-ar, gcc-ranlib, gcc-nm, and cc in your own path, say at ~/.local/bin, where they will be found at the default path set for you on login. Then, system tools see the original gcc, but you get to seamlessly use the new on one development projects.